# How can I get container object in repository class without passing parameter?

Tags: symfony

> How can I get container object in repository class without passing
>   parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get container object as follow:

```
// include files to get container
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;

class ClassNameRepository extends EntityRepository implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     *
     * @author Ashok Chitroda <ashok.chitroda@gmail.com>
     */
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Ashok Chitroda

Comment: It works, but don't do this. It's a bad practice in general. By injecting a container you inject a whole world of services and that basically makes your repository dependent on virtually anything.

Comment: @Jakub Zalas, Is there any other way?

Comment: @ChintanMirani yes. Design properly and don't give your entities the responsibilities that don't belong to them. If you really need to pass a service to your entity, do it explicitly and pass the service in a method call you need that service in. Not ideal, but at least your entity dependencies are visible.