# EntityManager is closed due unique violation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony3 and I have a unique constraint in my rates table.

So when I trying to run this script twice, second run of course I get an exception. But after that I have closed EntityManager.

How could I handle this without manually check if the table already contains such row:

```
$rate = new Rate;
$rate->setCreatedAt($date);
$rate->setValue($rateValue);

try {
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($rate);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
} catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
    var_dump($this->getEntityManager()->isOpen()); // false
}
```

Comment: The entity manager is not designed to be used after an exception is thrown.  There are a few tricks but for all practical purposes you just need to start over.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for an existing entity beforehand:

```
$existingRate = $this->getEntityManager()
                     ->getRepository(Rate::class)
                     ->findOneBy... // use what method suits you

if(!$existingRate) {
    $rate = new Rate;
    $rate->setCreatedAt($date);
    $rate->setValue($rateValue);
    // insert only if not found
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($rate);
} else {
    // update if found
    $existingRate->setValue($rateValue);
}

// you may wrap this in a try-catch to prevent other errors
$this->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

Another option would be to rebuild/reset the entity manager

```
if ($this->getEntityManager()->isOpen() === false) {
    // reset or generate a new entity manager
}
```

Comment: "How could I handle this without manually check if the table already contains such row"

Answer (score 0):

You could reset your entity manager

```
$this->getDoctrine()->resetManager()
```

From docs:

> This method is useful when an object manager has been closed because
>   of a rollbacked transaction AND when you think that it makes sense to
>   get a new one to replace the closed one.

However it would be better to check if your transaction will fail before executing it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to getDoctrine method, because I run the code inside my repository class (sorry forgot to mention).

Comment: You could have a look at this where its shown how to access container from within repository. But as also written in this post it seems ti be bad practice.... Try to check your constraints before persisting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663626/how-can-i-get-container-object-in-repository-class-without-passing-parameter But

Comment: This is good solution, especially when you can't check constraints because of performance reasons.

Comment: @JamesMay FYI, `getDoctrine()` returns a `ManagerRegistry` instance, which is always injected into your repository class constructor as you have to pass it on to the superclass constructor. So you can easily call `resetManager()` on it from within your repository class.